# How can I define the Postgres template to use when creating DBs with Doctrine2?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL as the DB backend for a new Symfony2 + Doctrine2 project. I'd like to take advantage of some of the features of PostGIS, and as such have created a Postgres template for PostGIS.

Right now, I can't see how to tell Doctrine2 to use the PostGIS template instead of the default, looking through the Doctrine2 code hasn't lead me anywhere (to be honest, I'm struggling to figure out how it even works).

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: I don't know Doctrine2, but there is nothing wrog with installing PostGIS into template1 which is the default template used when nothing is specified.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yeah but that's no good for all other PGSQL sites running off the same DB server (unless, of course the overhead of the bigger template is negligible, but that's a separate question!)

Answer (score 0):

One of your very basic problems is likely to be the fact that when you abstract, you lose low level control.  To my knowledge template databases are not likely to be common concepts elsewhere.  So you really have to drop to a lower level, connect to the postgres db manually and issue your `CREATE DATABASE foo WITH TEMPLATE bar` statement yourself.